# Cant show the icon by using API

Tags: javascript, html, api

Hope everyone is well.

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="location">
        <h1 class="location-timezone">Timezone</h1> 
        <img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04n.png" id ="image" alt=""class="icon" />
</div>
```

By using "openweathermap.org" API, I am trying to get the icon value. I have already got the temperature and other things. But when it comes to change the icon value, it doesnt change.

Below, I have attached my JavaScript code:

```
const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid={API KEY}`
        fetch(api)
            .then(response =>{
            return response.json(); 
        })
            .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            const { icon} = data.weather[0];
            iconButton.src=`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png`
```

My question is what exactly I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is iconButton , can you share code for it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the api, but everything seems to work fine.
It's probably the way you're changing the `iconButton.src`.

See if this sample helps:

```js
var sample = {"coord":{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":300.15,"pressure":1007,"humidity":74,"temp_min":300.15,"temp_max":300.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":160},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1485790200,"sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.2064,"country":"AU","sunrise":1485720272,"sunset":1485766550},"id":2172797,"name":"Cairns","cod":200};

const { icon } = sample.weather[0]

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.icon').src = `https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png`
})
```

```html
<div class="location">
  <h1 class="location-timezone">Timezone</h1>
  <img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04n.png" id="image" alt="" class="icon" />
</div>

<button>Fetch new weather</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried the way you write. Working now. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @TaufiqueAzad Glad it worked. Make sure the accept the answer  to help someone else in the future. Good luck !